# How can i make a nav bar that takes me to diffrent contaners of the page

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm making a nav bar but because the web site I'm building, is pretty small I want to make a nav bar that takes the user to different containers of the page

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You give the container an ID and use #theID as the href in an  tag:

```html
<body>
    <nav>
        <a href="#container_1">Container 1</a>
        <a href="#container_2">Container 2</a>
        <a href="#container_3">Container 3</a>
    </nav>

    <div id="container_1"></div>
    <div id="container_2"></div>
    <div id="container_3"></div>
</body>
```

You can make it scroll smoothly, by adding `scroll-behavior: smooth;` to the  tag like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html style="scroll-behavior: smooth;">
    <!-- content -->
</html>
```

If you don´t want to change the URL or don´t want to use an  tag you can use `element.scrollIntoViewIfNeeded()` in the click event like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html style="scroll-behavior: smooth;">
    <body>
        <nav>
            <p id="container_1_link">Container 1</p>
            <p id="container_2_link">Container 2</p>
            <p id="container_3_link">Container 3</p>
        </nav>

        <div id="container_1"></div>
        <div id="container_2"></div>
        <div id="container_3"></div>

        <script>
            document.querySelector('#container_1_link').addEventListener("click", () => { document.querySelector('#container_1').scrollIntoViewIfNeeded(); });
            document.querySelector('#container_2_link').addEventListener("click", () => { document.querySelector('#container_2').scrollIntoViewIfNeeded(); });
            document.querySelector('#container_3_link').addEventListener("click", () => { document.querySelector('#container_3').scrollIntoViewIfNeeded(); });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please consider waiting for the asker to add their own effort

Comment: For me the question was short but clear enough to understand the problem. But I will next time

Comment: The question does make sense and the question also shows no effort